# displaying text using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a button for a NEA project but first of all apparently there is no such thing as an inbuilt button. Also when im trying to create a button I want to have text over a drawn rectangle. when I launch the code, pygame creates a black window but then goes unresponsive. I'm not sure but i think this is because i dont have any python installed fonts in my pc so it can't write anything. How can i fix this?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("calibri", "30")
gameDisplay = pygame.display.sey_mode((960,960))
pygame.display.set_caption("")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))
quit = false
while not quit:

   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           quit = True

      gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
      pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, (380,700,200,80), 0)
      Online_start_text = font.render("Online", True, (0,0,0))
      Online_start_textRect.center = (480, 800)
   pygame.display.flip()
   clock.tick(10)
```

Comment: There are a lot of typos in your code: `30"` -> `30`, `false` -> `False`,  `sey_mode` -> `set_mode`. Furthermore there seem to be some [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) issues.

Comment: @Rabbid76 . i wrote it all out instead of copy pasting to remove unnecesary lines. when everything is correctly indented and there are no typos it goes unresponsive

Comment: @Rabbid76 im not sure what you mean. im assuming the event loop is the ```for event in pygame.event.get(): ```

Comment: Do not draw the scene in the event loop. Draw it in the application loop.

Comment: ```while not quit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit = True


    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, (380,700,200,80), 0)
    Online_start_text = font.render("Online", True, (0,0,0))
    Online_start_textRect = Online_start_text.get_rect()
    Online_start_textRect.center = (480, 800)
    

    pygame.display.flip() ```
this is the new change i made. it shows the "button" but there is still no text on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pygame


FPS = 10
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

HEIGHT, WIDTH = 960, 960
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((HEIGHT, WIDTH))
pygame.display.set_caption("")

pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("calibri", 30)
online_start_text = font.render("Online", True, BLACK)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

quit = False
while not quit:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           quit = True

    game_display.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, BLUE, (380,700,200,80), 0))
    game_display.blit(online_start_text, (480 - online_start_text.get_width() // 2,
                                          390 - online_start_text.get_height() // 2
                                          ))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Does this work for you? Apologies not at my computer so I can't test it until tomorrow.

Comment: yes this works. i dont understand what exactly has changed and why it makes a difference

Comment: Not sure if it's fixed in your actual code but yes like has been said by others there were a lot of spelling mistakes but also the code inside the while loop was also all inside the event loop, so your clock.tick(10) was happening for every single event in the event loop and so your program was unresponsive (as pygame assumes an error has occurred if you don't go through the full event loop often enough). Anything else you don't understand or is that ok?

Comment: this definitly did. i plugged it in to my original code and works fine now. i think i understand it now too so hopefully i can fix it if something similar happens again